# sp_executesql with user defined table type not working with two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use `variables` from different databases (hier called Database1 and Database2) and to execute `sp_executesql` statement.

```
 USE Database1
 DECLARE @testVariable BIT = 1

 USE Database2
 DECLARE @Param1 t_ID
 DECLARE @Param2 t_ID
 DECLARE @Param3 VARCHAR(100) = '01.01.2010'
 DECLARE @Param4 VARCHAR(100) = '31.12.2015'
 DECLARE @Param5 VARCHAR(100) = '1'
 DECLARE @Param6 VARCHAR(100) = 'EUR'
 DECLARE @ParamDefinition  NVARCHAR(1000) = ''
 DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(1000) = ''
 DECLARE @SQLObject VARCHAR(100) = ''
 INSERT INTO @Param1 VALUES (1) ,(345), (123)
 INSERT INTO @Param2 VALUES (106)

 SET @SQLObject = 'Database2.dbo.Testfunction2'
 SET @SQLString =  'SELECT * FROM ' + @SQLObject + '(@Param1, @Param2,  @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6)'
 SET @ParamDefinition = '@Param1 t_ID READONLY, @Param2 t_ID READONLY, @Param3 VARCHAR(100), @Param4 VARCHAR(100), @Param5 VARCHAR(100), @Param6  VARCHAR(100)'

 IF @testVariable = 1
 BEGIN
       EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4, @Param5, @Param6
 END
```

In my`sp_executesql`  statement I have also two ***Variables*** with user defined table types `@Param1 t_ID` and `@Param2 t_ID`. This Type is created in both Databases. 
If I comment `--USE Database1` and run the code above, so that I stay within only one DB (Database2) for the whole process, there is no error,
but when I try to run the same procedure with using of two Databases: `USE Database1` and `USE Database2`, I get a compatibility error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure PROC_Test, Line 0
```

`Operand type clash: t_ID is incompatible with t_ID`

What am I doing wrong? Is there any problem solving?

Comment: What is the definition of t_ID, and what is the purpose of the first USE statement?

Comment: This Type is only to get ids: `CREATE TYPE [dbo].[t_ID] AS TABLE(
 [id] [int] NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)` and actually this sp_executesql statement muss run in this first USE --> in  `Database1`

Comment: Variables have scope of the current batch. They are not database specific.

Comment: Is `Testtable2` actually a table or is it a very poorly named function? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, Testtable2 is some Function, which has 6 Parameters